# TYPO3 CMS 9 LTS: PersistedAliasMapper with same slugs in different storagePids

Tags: routes, typo3

I've got a setup with two sites. Each site has an extension for my model tx_myext_domain_model_product and this product has a slug. The slug is unique for a site, but not within the whole instance. So, `product-a` may be the same slug for two different products, residing in different storagePids.

Using the usual PersistedAliasMapper I cannot find a way to define the storage pid for the mapped record, so in some cases I get the wrong record.

```
routeEnhancers:
  Products:
    aspects:
      slug:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_myext_domain_model_product
        routeFieldName: slug
```

A quick visualization:

```
uid,   pid,              title,       slug,        description
"1",   "10 [in Site A]", "Product A", "product-a", "Description in Site A"
"2",   "20 [in Site B]", "Product A", "product-a", "differing description in Site B"
```

Is there a way to define the storagePid, so the mapping query fetches not only by mapped title, but also by folder (or site)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been a bug prior to 9.5.15/9.5.16. I updated from .14 to .16 and the behavior is correct now.